# Why click event fires even it is removed?

Tags: angular, angular6

in my App I **add a click listener** via function activateListener().
On some point at the run-time I **remove the click listener** via function deactivatelistener().
But **still** when the user does a **click** the click function pingIfLastPingIsOld() **is called again**.
The function activateListener() is not called again after deactivatelistener().

Does some body have a glue how comes?
**Why the click listener is still working?**

Frank

```js
    activateListener() {
        window.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.pingIfLastPingIsOld();
        });
    }

    deactivatelistener() {
        window.removeEventListener('click', this.pingIfLastPingIsOld);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing answer by Cétia correctly identifies the issue - you register a click handler with an anonymous function, but then try to unregister a named function - however I would like to provide an alternative solution.

---

I see you're using an anonymous function as your click listener, I assume this is to fix the `this` context for the execution of `pingIfLastPingIsOld`. This can also be done via the `.bind` method.

```
constructor() {
    this.pingIfLastPingIsOld = this.pingIfLastPingIsOld.bind(this);
}

activateListener() {
    window.addEventListener('click', this.pingIfLastPingIsOld);
}

deactivatelistener() {
    window.removeEventListener('click', this.pingIfLastPingIsOld);
}
```

Regardless of where `pingIfLastPingIsOld` is invoked from, it will now execute with the component as the value of `this`.

---

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 1):

It's normal because you didn't register/unregsiter the exact same method. Do this :

```
activateListener() {
    window.addEventListener('click', this.pingIfLastPingIsOld);
}

deactivatelistener() {
    window.removeEventListener('click', this.pingIfLastPingIsOld);
}
```

But, the angular way would be more :

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
public onClick(targetElement) {
    // your stuff
}
```

Comment: Your "Angular" way may be a significant change in behavior. Previously, the click listener was only active after `activateListener` was called, and would stop if `deactivateListener` was called. Using the `@HostListener` means that the click handler will be active as long as the component is loaded.